# App frequently crashes on certain content

Tags: bug, android-app

It's actually hard for me to reproduce, but I have this problem now already for multiple months, so I try to explain what seems to be causing it.

When starting the app and opening a from my notifications or HNQ's, it occasionally crashes.

I'm assuming this is related to attributes of comments or answers.
Since when I'm posting a question myself, I can open it without trouble. But mostly at some point when a new comment or answer is added, the app crashes somewhere halfway in loading the post. That specific question then can't be opened by my app for a period of some hours through i.e. notification links or that alike.

I can workaround this by switching to the Stack Exchange site of that post and looking it up in the "Top Questions" list, because loading the question from that list doesn't cause the crash. But doing so is sometimes a bit tricky.

Is this known? Can I add any additional information for identifying how to reproduce it?

Comment: Could you mention the app version? I haven't heard this issue, or it's still a bit vague to non-devs (linking to the specific question/comment might help). It *seems* like a race-condition between read-only slave database, but knowing that you could open the post from question list... might not be the case. You're free to add additional information to help reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can start adding time and posts when ever it will occur in the future if that might be of use. Actually im using 1.0.83 im confused about copyright is stated to b XXXX-2015. As if the version is outdated. But the appstore actually says Im up to date